# Define/attach Persistence Volume claim in application.properties

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, persistent-volume-claims

I would like to define or more "attach" a persistance volume claim (which is already present in K8s and named "pvc-vol-divacms-epass") and all I can see in the documentation is that there is a property "quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes" for which the type is defined as "Map<String, PersistentVolumeClaimVolume>".
2 questions:

- is that the right property to use
- if no, which one should I use and how do I use it; if yes, how do I enter values for "Map<String, PersistentVolumeClaimVolume>" in the application.properties file?

My K8s portion in the file looks like this

```
quarkus.container-image.group=dwamara
quarkus.container-image.name=${quarkus.application.name}
quarkus.container-image.tag=version_tag
quarkus.kubernetes.namespace=divacms-dev

quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.expose=true
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.host=gateway.divacms.${application.host}
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy your cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Just add something like:

```
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.epass.claim-name=pvc-vol-divacms-epass
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.db.readonly=false
```

to `application.properties`.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life :-)  I've added<br>
```
quarkus.kubernetes.mounts.epass.path=${qrcode.folder}
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.epass.claim-name=pvc-vol-divacms-epass
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.db.readonly=false
```
and it did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, you saved my life :-)  I've added

```
quarkus.kubernetes.mounts.epass.path=${qrcode.folder}
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.epass.claim-name=pvc-vol-divacms-epass
quarkus.kubernetes.pvc-volumes.db.readonly=false
```

and it did the trick.

Thanks,
D.